# Reducing the call to the same class several times

Tags: python-3.x

I have problem - can I do reduction on calling same class 9 times?

```
        self.level1 = LevelButton(10, 10, "1", "black", "lightgreen")
        self.level2 = LevelButton(50, 10, "1", "black", "lightgreen")
        self.level3 = LevelButton(100, 10, "1", "black", "lightgreen")
        self.level4 = LevelButton(150, 10, "1", "black", "lightgreen")
        self.level5 = LevelButton(200, 10, "1", "black", "lightgreen")
        self.level6 = LevelButton(250, 10, "1", "black", "lightgreen")
        self.level7 = LevelButton(300, 10, "1", "black", "lightgreen")
        self.level8 = LevelButton(350, 10, "1", "black", "lightgreen")
        self.level9 = LevelButton(400, 10, "1", "black", "lightgreen")
```

There is class LevelButton:

```
class LevelButton:
    x_0 = 0
    y_0 = 0
    text = ""
    fg_color = (0, 0, 0)
    bg_color = (0, 0, 0)

    def __init__(self, x_0, y_0, text, fg_color, bg_color):
        self.x_0 = x_0
        self.y_0 = y_0
        self.text = text
        self.fg_color = fg_color
        self.bg_color = bg_color
```

Can I reduce it to one - two lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of these  `LevelButton` objects.
like this-

```
levelButtonList = []
i0=10
i1=50
for i in range(1,10):
    if i==1:
        levelButtonList.append(LevelButton(i0,10, "1", "black", "lightgreen"))
    else:
        levelButtonList.append(LevelButton(i1,10, "1", "black", "lightgreen"))
        i1+=50
```

After that you can access them separately by using index of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this code:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    _i = max(10, (i - 1)*50)
    value = LevelButton(_i, 10, "1", "black", "lightgreen")
    self.__setattr__(f"level{i}", value)
```

Two liner:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    self.__setattr__(f"level{i}", LevelButton(max(10, (i - 1)*50), 10, "1", "black", "lightgreen"))
```